# Get ActiveRecord value with outer index on Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When I get List of Members in controller, I think @Members is array of ActiveRecord.

*member_controller.rb*

```
@members = Member.where(params[:param1])
```

So I know normally I write below to display.
*member.html.erb*

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
    <%= member.name %>
<% end %>
```

But in case of below, I would like to write index number at least loop 10 times like this.

```
<% (0..10).each do |idx| %>
    <%= idx %>:
    <%= members[idx].name %>
<% end %>
```

But it does not work. It can not be displayed members[idx].name
How can I make it?

Comment: Umm.. You now changed the question's error. Explain what did you mean by **But it does not work** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. It worked!!

```
<% (0..10).each do |idx| %>
    <%= idx %>:
    <%= @members[idx].nil? ? '': @members[idx].name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's working as you want? You're asking if the results in @members variable are nil, but I think you should be asking if @members[idx] is nil. I mean: @members[idx].nil? ? '' : @members[idx].name

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use each_with_index method?

```
<% @members.each_with_index do |member, index| %>
  <%= index %>
  <%= member.name %>
<% end %>
```

If you need only 10 records, limit @members at the controller:

```
@members = Member.where(column: params[:column]).limit(10)
```

Does this help you?

Comment: In case of result are 2, even if I use .limit(10), I misunderstood the number of results also return 2 not 10. I did not know it returns 10 results.

Comment: If the result of record are 2, does it loop only 2 times, right? I would like to make loops 10 times at least.

Comment: This loop will run once per each member in @members. If you have 2 records, will run 2 times. If you want to run it 10 times, what would you display in member.name? Just a blank space? member variable would be nil

Answer (score 2):

Fix is

```
<% (0..10).each do |idx| %>
    <%= idx %>:
    <%= @members[idx].name %>
<% end %>
```

You forgot to use `@`. It should be `@members`, not `members`. And, if your query to the controller returns less than `10`, then your *looping* way will crash. You will get the error,[NoMethodError](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/NoMethodError.html) like `NoMethodError: undefined method name' for nil:NilClass`.

You can do as,

```
<% @members.each_index do |idx| %>
    <%= idx %>:
    <%= @members[idx].name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yup. This. Voted up. Also, let's highlight that the OP's code will crash in case < 10 members are returned. Preferable would be using limit along with each_with_index

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`each_with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index):

```
<% @members.each_with_index do |member, idx| %>
    <%= idx %>:
    <%= member.name %>
<% end %>
```

You could then use [`limit`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset) to limit the number of records returned.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
<% (0..10).each do |idx| %>
    <%= idx %>:
    <%= @members[idx].name %> #you forgot '@'here
<% end %>
```

Though each_with_index is a better option here